# Redundant Data Insertion in a Multithreaded Environment without Database Constraints

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

In a Spring application, there's a transactional method A designed to verify if a user's email exists in the user table. If the email doesn't exist, the method proceeds to insert the user; otherwise, it returns an exception. However, when multiple threads concurrently call this service or controller with the same user, redundant data may be inserted into the database.

Considering the use of transactions, what strategies or techniques can i employ to resolve this issue and prevent the insertion of redundant data without adding additional constraints to the database schema? How can you ensure data consistency in a multithreaded environment where multiple calls attempt to insert the same user concurrently?

example

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void verifyAndInsertUser(User user) {
        User existingUser = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());

        if (existingUser == null) {
            userRepository.save(user);  // Optimistic locking handled by JPA
        } else {
            throw new UserExistsException("User with email " + user.getEmail() + " already exists.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not be stupid and do it in the database? If you don't want duplicate emails, don't allow duplicate emails. If you really really want to make your life complicated then lock the user table before checking for an existing email so nobody else can insert at the same time as you.

Comment: Why rebuilding standard database functionality? A simple unique constraint will do the job. This also creates the index (a unique index) needed, to keep it fast.